# What's a smart way to loop an animation with the camera constantly moving aroud?

Tags: animation

Suppose I have an animation that is 16 frames and I wanted to keep looping this over and over for 128 frames (8 times) while the camera pans around this animation. Is there any way to do this without copy and pasting the animation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what the *Nonlinear Animation Editor* is made for.

In the *Dope Sheet* in *Action Editor* mode, select the action and click on the *Push Down* button:

[image]

This will remove the action from the *Dope Sheet*, but it's now available in the *Nonlinear Animation Editor* as a yellow strip:

[image]

Keep this strip selected, open the N panel of the *Nonlinear Animation Editor*, click on the *Strip* tag and under *Action Clip* choose the *Repeat* number:

[image]

To make the action come back in the *Dope Sheet* if you ever need to edit it, select the strip and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> or simply select it in the dropdown menu of the *Dope Sheet*:

[image]